# no of rooms in a dropdown issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to show no of available rooms in a room type..Currently i can show all the rooms..But when checking the date range how can i hide the booked rooms from the drop down??

**Room types table**

```
room_id  || name || max || hotel_id || no_rooms 
   1         a       4        01           4
   2         b       1        02           2
   3         c       2        01           3
   4         d       4        02           4
   5         e       4        04           10
```

**Bookings table**

```
id  || room_type_id ||  hotel_id ||      check_in      ||  check_out
1           1             01       2015-03-18 11:26:04   2015-03-20 11:26:04
2           1             01       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
3           2             01       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
4           3             02       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
```

So from the room types table i'm getting the no_rooms value and then i'm iterating it as,
 **eg**:- if it is **4** then **1 2 3 4** in the dropdown.

But how can i hide the booked rooms??..As in if one room is booked from above 4 then it should 3 **eg** : **1 2 3** in the dropdown.

I have below sql to check the availability but how can i hide it from the dropdown?

```
SELECT * FROM bookings bk 
JOIN room_types rt ON rt.room_id = bk.room_type_id 
WHERE bk.hotel_id = '" . (int)$hotelid . "' 
AND bk.check_in 
NOT BETWEEN  '".$chkin."' 
AND '".$chkout."' 
AND bk.check_out 
NOT BETWEEN '".$chkin."' 
AND '".$chkout."' 
AND (bk.check_in >= '".$chkin."' OR bk.check_out <= '".$chkout."')
```

Comment: *"how can i hide the booked rooms from the drop down?"* - What dropdown?

Comment: just a simple dropdown html select dropdown...im using while loop to show number of rooms there.. like if 4 rooms 1 to 4........1,2,3,4 @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM room_types tr
WHERE tr.hotel_id = '" . (int)$hotelid . "'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                 FROM bookings bk 
                 WHERE rt.room_id = bk.room_type_id 
                 AND '".$chkin."'  <= bk.check_out 
                 AND '".$chkout."' >= bk_check_in
               )
```

Comment: how can i loop this through a select list??

Comment: loop on what? I need more info